# MOSFET Gate Driver Simulation Problem

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am trying to simulate high side MOSFET in Proteus using gate driver IC [IR2112](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2112.pdf) but it does not work as expected when HIN is high. The mosfet should be turned ON when gate voltage is more than 10V but it gives across R4 the same voltage Vc as applied to IC pin 3 when HIN is high. I need to learn how to overcome the mentioned problem.

[image: Gate Driver Simulation Problem]

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens? This type of driver uses a charge pump (D1, C1, C2) to generate the gate voltage; is your simulation allowing it to charge up?

Comment: @DaveTweed Actually, the problem is that transistor is not conducting when more than 10V are applied to gate. I need to have output 100V across R4 when HIN is high. The capacitors are charged during simulation.

Comment: May I ask what software is being used to perform this simulation? I am currently trying to perform a similar simulation on my gate driver ic and I am having trouble finding software where I can accurately simulate my ic asd well as my circuit. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @L_t130 Proteus software is used here for designing and simulation of electronic circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The IR2112 uses a charge pump (C2 and D1) to increase Gate drive voltage. For this to work properly you must apply PWM to HIN, which keeps C2 charged up.

Each time the FET turns on it pulls the load voltage high. Since C2 is already charged up to nearly 15V, and D1 stops it from discharging into the 15V supply, the boost voltage at VB will go up to almost 15V above the FET's Drain voltage (ie. to about 115V). The driver then switches between this boost voltage and VS, providing close to 15V Gate drive to the FET even though it is way above VC. C2 will loose some charge through the gate drive circuit, but when the FET is turned off again (during PWM off time) it is recharged through the load (R4).

If you hold HIN high continuously then C2 will continue to discharge through R1 and R2. Eventually the drive voltage will drop below the FETs threshold voltage and it will start to turn off, then boost voltage will drop and you will be left with only the 15V from VS. The load voltage will drop even lower because the IRF840 needs about 6V to turn on.

Another potential problem with your circuit is that C2 is being discharged through R1 and R2 almost as fast as it is being charged through R4. Over many PWM cycles the average voltage on C2 will drop, reducing Gate drive. At 50% PWM or above the drive voltage might drop below the FETs threshold voltage, causing it to turn off too soon. This can be fixed by either increasing the value of R2 or reducing the value of R4.